# MPAndroid Chart with json data from Volley

Tags: java, android, android-volley, mpandroidchart

I'm using MPAndroid Chart, and I'm following the tutorial here [Android Bar & Radar Chart using Volley MSQL PHP JSON](https://steemit.com/android/@sumitrajpal/android-bar-and-radar-chart-using-volley-msql-php-json)

However, I'm getting this error

[image]

How can I fix this TIA.

I am using MPAndroidChart 3.0.3

Answer (score 1):

> **Your solution is here**

Because the MPchart Can't set his description by String.

```
Description description = new Description();
description.setText("Add Your string here");
chart.setDescription(description);
```

> **You can set BarData like below code :**

```
BarDataSet set1;
set1 = new BarDataSet(xValue, "");
set1.setDrawIcons(true);
set1.setStackLabels(new String[]{"Male", "Female"});
set1.setDrawValues(true);
set1.setValueTextSize(12f);
set1.setColors(ColorTemplate.JOYFUL_COLORS);

BarData data1 = new BarData(set1);
data1.setBarWidth(15f);
positiveChart.setData(data1);
positiveChart.setFitBars(true);
positiveChart.invalidate();
```

Comment: I have a follow up question below... it works saomehow

Answer (score 0):

thanks, but I cannot display the "text" value of X-axis, it will become numeric and goes to Y-axis, and the value of Y-axis became the labels of X-axis...
[image]

Comment: Then what's the problem. ? , i will send you my code. check and compare with your code.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is the problem,

Candidates name should be in X axis,
Scores in Y axis,
But look at the chart... Wrong destination of x and y, and the value of each x a is became nos